# use Google Maps Directions API without key on android app

Tags: android, google-maps

i know this a duplicate question but i did not have an answer for my situation.
i know when use direction api without a key, google has 2,500 free directions requests per day limit.
and the limit per IP-address (because there is no key).
My question is : if my app is installed on 10 different devices, does each on has a daily 2500 free requests or google can detect in some way the package name and set a limit on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every IP has it's own limit. Google doesn't check for package name.